# Why any response in unit test with MVVM in android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-mvvm

I would like to cover my ViewModel with some tests. For that point I created such test:

```
class AppViewModelTest {
    lateinit var mainViewModel: AppViewModel

    @Mock
    lateinit var apiService: RetrofitService


    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)

        mainViewModel = AppViewModel(MainRepository(apiService))
    }

    @Test
    fun test_1() {
        println("test was started")
        mainViewModel.logIn(JsonObject().apply {
            addProperty("username", "loginStr")
            addProperty("password", "passStr")
            addProperty("type", "mobile")
        }) {
            println(it.isSuccessful)
        }
    }
}
```

during the debugging I saw that I entered into the viemodel method, but I don't see any response output. I'm testing such method:

```
   fun logIn(jsonObject: JsonObject, callBack: (res: Response<AppAuthModel>) -> Unit) {
        job?.cancel()
        job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val response = mainRepository.logIn(jsonObject)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                callBack.invoke(response)
            }
        }
    }
```

and I can not enter `callBack.invoke(response)`. Why does it happen? My repository method is here:

```
suspend fun logIn(loginObject: JsonObject) = retrofitService.auth(loginObject)
```

and it works in the app, not in the test.

### UPDATE:

Finally I have such test:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class AppViewModelTest {
    private val testDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()
    lateinit var mainViewModel: AppViewModel
    lateinit var mainRepository: MainRepository

    @Mock
    lateinit var apiService: RetrofitService

    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutionRule: InstantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()


    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
        mainRepository = MainRepository(apiService)
        mainViewModel = AppViewModel(mainRepository)
    }

    @Test
    fun getAllMoviesTest() {
        runBlocking {
            Mockito.`when`(mainRepository.logIn(JsonObject().apply {
                addProperty("username", "test")
                addProperty("password", "password")
            })).thenReturn(Response.success(AppAuthModel("test_Access_token", "", 11)))

            mainViewModel.logIn(JsonObject().apply {
                addProperty("username", "test")
                addProperty("password", "password")
            }) {
                println("getting some response")
                println(it.body()?.access_token)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

but it does not work. I tried to make own dispatcher:

```
@get:Rule
private val testDispatcher = MainCoroutineRule()
```

with such class:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class MainCoroutineRule : TestWatcher(), TestCoroutineScope by TestCoroutineScope() {

    override fun starting(description: Description) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(this.coroutineContext[ContinuationInterceptor] as CoroutineDispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description) {
        super.finished(description)
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

but it also does not work and I can not enter to the method. When I set directly rule `TestCoroutineScope` and in such case I can enter to coroutine scope in viewmodel, but my code scope:

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
callBack.invoke(response)
}
```

with callback is not invoked.

Comment: You're testing a view model, so all other mock invocations should be mocked. What you're currently doing is an attempt to test both the view model and the repository.

Comment: but how to mock viemodel correctly in such case? I tried to test it, and I need repository also for normal working of viewmodel

Comment: You don't need to mock the view model, because you're going to test it. You need to mock repository's `logIn()` method return value by using `when` or `whenever` or, most likely `coEvery`, depending on the JUnit framework you're using for tests.

Comment: can you share some example please, because I'm pretty new in mocking and unit testing, only experience in espresso tests :(

Comment: @Onik, can you please check the question new edition? I checked what you said before

Comment: It isn't clear what isn't working now, but what I can see is that `mainRepository ` is still not mocked, meaning it isn't annotated with `@Mock` so applying `MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)` makes nothing to it. Beside that, view model does not have a dependency on `apiService` - you don't need it in the test class.

Comment: okay, I added `@Mock` to `mainRepository`, at this moment I don't understand the main idea maybe of mocking, because I wrote sample of response as I see, but my the latest code scope with `callBack.invoke...` is not triggered at all.